# Combine two Observables with the second using results from the first one in parameters

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I have two methods that return an Observable< Response< ResponseBody > >

```
firstAPI.getFirstInfo("1", "2");

secondApi.getSecondInfo(resultFirstObservable, "3");
```

I'm trying to get an information from the first one and use it as a parameter in the second one.

I started by trying to use a flatMap:

```
Observable<Integer> mergedObservers = firstAPI.getFirstInfo("1","2")
    .flatMap((Response<ResponseBody> resultFirstObservable) -> {
        try {
            return secondApi.getSecondInfo(transformToTheFormatNeeded(resultFirstObservable.body().string()), "3");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return secondApi.getSecondInfo("defaultValue", "3");
        }
    }, ((Response<ResponseBody> resultFirstObservable), (Response<ResponseBody> resultSecondObservable)) -> {
        try {
            return transformToWhatINeed(resultSecondObservable.body().string());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

I would try then to subscribeOn this new Observable and onNext I would send the returned value to my Activity.

```
Subscription sub = mergedObservers.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .repeatWhen(completed -> completed.delay(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                    view.updateInfo(integer);
                }
            });
```

My problem is that the flatMap throws 2 errors at compilation:

1. error: lambda body is neither value nor void compatible
2. error: no suitable method found for 
   flatMap((__)->{ tr[...]; } },(.. ,..)->{ [...]; } })

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Suggested reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#dependent-sub-flows

Comment: when you have compile errors with lambdas, your types are wrong, please "expand lambdas to anonymous class" to get the full pictures, update the code so that everyone can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the API call actually throws an `IOException` while also returning an Observable. In addition, you have to return something from the second lambda but the try-catch there doesn't do that, causing the error. Try this:

```
Observable<Integer> mergedObservers = firstAPI.getFirstInfo("1","2")
.flatMap(resultFirstObservable -> {
    return secondApi.getSecondInfo(resultFirstObservable, "3")
        .onErrorResumeNext(e -> {
             e.printStackTrace();
             return secondApi.getSecondInfo("defaultValue", "3");
        });
}, (resultFirstObservable, resultSecondObservable) -> {
    try {
        return transformToWhatINeed(resultSecondObservable.body().string());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
});
```

Comment: The 2 IOExceptions were due to the .body().string(), and the lambda needed a return, but the return type wasn't accepted. So for the first lambda I made another call with the default value, as for the second I return a transformToWhatINeed([]). It seems to work. Thank you.

Comment: If "1" and "2" are variables, do you think that if I replace them with "variable1" and "variable2" that are changed sometimes in another methods, everytime the Subscription is completed, the next time they will be updated ?